# Remove duplicate entries in each column of a Data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, duplicates

Table 1 is a initial Data Frame.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anwct.png)

Table 2 is desired data frame.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yrwp0.png)

(I have 1000 Columns in the Original DF which need to be converted in to the format from Table 1 to table 2)

quick help will be appreciated

Need a code to run it in Jupiter notebook

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html) per columns with set default indices by [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
out = df.apply(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True))
```

Or use `Series` constructor with [`Series.unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stabltransfe/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html):

```
out = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.unique()))
```

Comment: I think it's an existing answer ;)

Comment: So do you still want me to tell you? You asked me once to do it.

Comment: Sorry, not understand, can you explain more what is problem?

Comment: You asked me one day to let you know when you post a dupe so that you can convert it to wiki as you like.

Comment: @mozway - thank you for explanation. I stop do it.